# The internal of hot reloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, websocket, hot-reload

I have been using webpack hot reload in development and it is awesome. It saves me a lot of time. I have been searching over the web today to get a good grasp of how it actually works and have not found any good explanation about the internal working of it. So, I am asking here to get a good understanding of how it actually works.

I have come a bit in my mini hot reload project. For now, I have set up a node server and a simple client side Javascript code. The client is connected to the server via websocket and the server fires change events to client based on `fs.watch` function from `node.js`that watched my code folder for every file change.

I am stuck at how I can patch the update I recieve from server in client code. Right now, I have just `index.js` file in `index.html`. So I am wondering how bundling tools like `webpack` achieves hot reload, specifically how they patch the update.

I've read from `webpack` docs that they have a thin hrm runtime in client code that update the patch, but I could not seem to find any detailed info on how they achieve this feat. Do they open the client `index.js` file using `FileReader`, read the file and write(?) back? Again, I do not have a clear understanding of how this works. So, if you guys could give me some direction, I could dig deeper into it.

So my question is, how do they patch(insert) the new code into the already existing client code which resides in `index.js`?

Comment: That is tricky and flaky, i'm fighting to find a better solution to do this too. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/HotModuleReplacement.runtime.js this is the code that lives on the browser. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/HotModuleReplacementPlugin.js this is what controls the updates too

Comment: @PlayMa256 I have looked through that code yesterday and find nothing specifically about how they patch the update. Do you have a clue on how it happens inside that code that lives in the browser?

Comment: it stats on line 547 i suppose. it plays with `module` and also with the array of installed modules (aka webpackjsonp) on the browser.

Comment: If you not tied to the `webpack-hot-middleware` an alternative could be the [webpack-hot-client](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-hot-client) which uses [more recent technologies](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-hot-client/issues/18) and IMO easier to configure, and follow what it does and how.

Comment: @lependu I want to code myself this up since we do not use webpack in our project. From my reading, webpack-hot-client is closely tied to webpack itself. ```In order to use webpack-hot-client, your webpack config should include an entry option that is set to an Array of String..```